# Python: Tkinter Menu entries do not pass correct value

Tags: python, menu, drop-down-menu, tkinter, menuitem

I am currently working on a GUI (Tkinter) for my application. I am having problems with creating a couple of dropdown menus that should be used to choose a date. The application that I have written creates the desired menus with labels, however, by clicking any of the buttons only the value of the last menu entry gets passed to the tkinter mutable IntVar.

This is a portion of the code that emphasizes my problem. year should be the year that the user clicks upon, however, it is always 2011.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog as dialog
import datetime
import calendar

window = Tk()
text = Text(window)
text.pack()

year = IntVar()
list_of_years = [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011]

def year_seter(value):
  year.set(value)

menubar = Menu(window)
yearmenu = Menu(menubar)
for the_year in list_of_years:
  yearmenu.add_command(label=str(the_year), command=lambda : year_seter(the_year))
menubar.add_cascade(label = 'Year', menu=yearmenu)
window.config(menu=menubar)

label = Label(window, textvariable=year)
label.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Can somebody please explain to me, why is this happening? 
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `command` to:

```
lambda the_year=the_year: year_seter(the_year)
```

The problem has to do with how Python looks up the value of `the_year`.
When you use

```
lambda : year_seter(the_year)
```

`the_year` is not in the local scope of the lambda function, so Python goes looking for it in the [extended, global, then builtin scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules). It finds it in the global scope. The `for-loop` uses `the_year`, and after the for-loop ends, `the_year` retains its last value, 2011. Since the lambda function is executed after the for-loop has ended, the value Python assigns to `the_year` is 2011.

In contrast, if you use a parameter with a default value, the default value is fixed at the time the function (lambda) is **defined**. Thus, each `lambda` gets a different value for `the_year` fixed as the default value.

Now when the lambda is called, again Python goes looking for the value of `the_year`, but this time finds it in the lambda's local scope. It binds the default value to `the_year`.

---

PS.

1. You could also forgo defining `year_seter` and just do:

   ```
   lambda the_year=the_year: year.set(the_year)
   ```
2. `list_of_years = range(1995,2012)` also works.

Comment: Wonderful answer and explanation. Thanks
The year_seter and list_of_years have been presented here in simplified form.